# how to pass "id" as a path variable via url from first page to second page and assign to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass the id of html card (when I click on it) to second page via URL as a path variable using JavaScript.
currently, the URL is like this : [www.xyz.com/page2.html?id=2](http://www.xyz.com/page2.html?id=2)

but I need to do the same function by sending the id as a path variable to second page like this

[www.xyz.com/page2.html/2](http://www.xyz.com/page2.html/2)

and assign that id to a variable in the second page. I need to do this using JavaScript or jQuery
Please someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to redirect the user to another page.

let's say

```
//cardID is the class value of the HTML card or we can use some other selector
$( ".cardID" ).on( "click", function() {
    var cardID = $(this).attr('id');
    window.location.replace("www.xyz.com/page2.html/"+cardID);
});
```

And on another page...

```
var url = window.location;
var urlAux = url.split('/');
var cardID = urlAux[2]
```

Comment: I Tried with this code but I cannot access the id from second page . It is showing me "Your file couldn’t be accessed"  in the page . I don't know the reason. Dou do you have any idea. about this @VPC ?